# Javassist - is it possible to change class from private to public

Tags: java, javassist

Is it possible, using javassist apis, to change a class inside a jar from private to public.
I already know how to unzip a jar, load ctclass, make change such as modify derived class name, then zip all to a new jar.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible to just call [CtClass.setModifiers()](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/html/javassist/CtClass.html#setModifiers%28int%29).

Comment: Hi Russell, thank you for your quick and correct answer. One more question for you if you know this, how to set a private method to public. I already got the CtClass, and I know the method name. Thank you very much.